# Include space as an acceptable output character

Tags: javascript, events, char, space

I have a contenteditable div with an id of "editable" in which I've simulated changing the character associated with a key event.  You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/66/

As you can see, no matter what alphanumeric key the user presses, the output string of "Singinme." types out in the div.  The spaces between the words in my var list are ignored.    I'd like the output to include spaces, and read "Sing in me." as it is currently written in the first line of my javascript code.  I've gotten help to at least identify that my problem is in the insertTextAtCursor function, but how do I change that function to include space as an acceptable output character?  Or, could I re-write my var list in a way that would type out as "Sing in me." in the div?

For convenience, I've pasted the javascript below as well.

PS:  I just found out that this is a browser issue.  In Chrome, it is as I described it.  In IE it works as I want it- "Sing in me." with spaces.  Any ideas how to make this work in Chrome?  I don't know if it works in firefox.

```
var list = "Sing in me.".split('');
function transformTypedCharacter(charStr) {
    return (/[a-zA-Z]/).test(charStr) ? list.shift()||" " : charStr;
}

function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
    var sel, range, textNode;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.deleteContents();
            textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            range.insertNode(textNode);

            // Move caret to the end of the newly inserted text node
            range.setStart(textNode, textNode.length);
            range.setEnd(textNode, textNode.length);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(text);
    }
}


$("#editable").keypress(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which) {
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
        var transformedChar = transformTypedCharacter(charStr);
        if (transformedChar != charStr) {
            insertTextAtCursor(transformedChar);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

​

Comment: but i am getting the output as Sing me in. with the spaces?

Comment: Interesting... Does the code look as it does when I pasted it above?  When I follow the link from my original question, I still get Singinme. without the spaces.

Comment: yup its ur code !!! m getting with spaces!!!

Comment: I tried it in IE and I get it with spaces too!  I was in Chrome before.  Any ideas how to make it work in multiple browsers?

Comment: no idea mate!!! Don't worry stackoverflow members will help u out with this issue!!! Cheer up!!!

Comment: What would be the actual application of this? I'm asking because the solution could depend on it.

Comment: Hi Jan, the application is that this is an art project.  I therefore have a lot of control over how the user approaches the program (as in a computer in a gallery space), and can make sure that only IE is used.  My question about other browsers is about convenience and possible expansion of the project to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome swallows the whitespace nodes. I can't tell whether this is a bug or not since as it seems multiple browsers treat whitespace and empty nodes differently.

In your case a simple solution is using non-breaking spaces instead. That's:

```
var list = "Sign\xA0in\xA0me.".split("");
```

Or

```
var list = "Sign in me.".replace(/\s/g, "\xA0").split("")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the spaces, for a solution to that check [@Alexander's great response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091952/78639). This is about other problems in your code.

First of all, you only match `a-z` and `A-Z` input characters. As in, you don't replace keystrokes such as `periods`, `space`, `numbers`, `non-ascii` letters etcetera. Secondly, instead of shifting the array, you should look for the character at the position in the input. With your code, you can delete the text and then it would not be replaced again.

```
function transformTypedCharacter(charStr) {
    var position = $("#editable").text().length;
    if (position >= list.length) return '';
    else return list[position];
}
```

Pair that with Alexander's answer and [you're home free](http://jsfiddle.net/vRXph/)!